# Bug in Rails 3 routes?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following in my `projects_controller`:

```
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.current_step = @project.first_step
  @user = current_user
end
```

And the following route in my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users do
 resources :projects
end
```

In my `views/users/show.html.erb` I have:

`<%= link_to image_tag('img_blank.png'), edit_user_project_path, :class => "btn_edit_project" %>`

and `rake routes` gives me:

```
...
  edit_user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:id/edit(.:format)      projects#edit
...
```

I am still getting the error:

```
`Routing Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"projects"}`
```

I am at wit's end on this one.  Any help?

Answer (score 2):

`edit_user_project_path` expects arguments: your `@user` and your `@project`:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('img_blank.png'), edit_user_project_path(@user, @project), :class => "btn_edit_project" %>
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem.  Funny, I have had this section of code working for 3 weeks and never saw this error before.  Is it possible that a new resource declaration in the routes.rb file could have made the argument inclusion necessary?

Comment: Ok, now when I go to actually click on the button, I get a `NoMethodError in ProjectsController#edit ` with the following output:

    `{"user_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x292fcb0>"}`

I don't understand why Rails is returning a reference to ActiveRecord instead of the project id.

Comment: You could try `@product.id` as the parameter instead. Though with your `@project = Project.find ...` code it shouldn't be assigning an ActiveRecord::Relation to `@project` -- did you change your controller code at all?